# Asp.net Membership Logged in Users list

Tags: asp.net

I used following in my application to find the list of logged in user. It gives the list of logged in user but when i close the browser and clear the browser history, it shows the user isonline status true. Please can any one tell me where i am wrong?

**When User signIn am validating user and redirect to url,**

```
if (user != null)
{
     if (Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, txtUserPassword.Text))
     {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, false);
     }
}
```

**List of logged in user code**

```
 MembershipUserCollection allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();

 MembershipUserCollection filteredUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();

 bool isOnline = true;
 foreach (MembershipUser user in allUsers)
 {
    // if user is currently online, add to gridview list
   if (user.IsOnline == isOnline)
   {
      filteredUsers.Add(user);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`MembershipUser.IsOnline` is not a very accurate check of whether or not a user is online. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline.aspx), a user is determined to be online:

> if the current date and time minus the
> UserIsOnlineTimeWindow property value is earlier than the
> LastActivityDate for the user.

This means the user could log in and then log out 10 seconds later and still be considered online.

So in your case you were logging in, checking the count, logging out, closing the browser, clearing cache, etc., but the user's `LastActivityDate` still fell within the assumed window described above. What you can do is:

- shorten the time window (which can produce some unwanted side
  effects)
- when logging the individual out, update their `LastActivityDate` to a
  time that would make the above check invalid (e.g., the current time
  `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow`)
- update the `LastActivityDate` manually at certain key points (e.g.,
  if your site is bookstore, maybe updating the `LastActivityDate` when
  they add an item to the cart)